# I am working in terminal application(Python+MySQL)

Tags: python, mysql, terminal

```
def view_empdetails():  #this is my function: it works great
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="#####",database="#DB")
    cursor = conn.cursor()  # this is database connection
    viw = """select * from employees"""
    cursor.execute(viw)
    for emp_no,first_name,last_name,gender,DOB,street,city,state,zipcode,email,phone,hire_date in cursor.fetchall():  # fetch all data from employee table in DB
        print('-'*50)
        print(emp_no)
        print(first_name)
        print(last_name)
        print(gender)
        print(DOB)
        print(street)
        print(city)
        print(state)        # I need all these output be in a table or organize format 
        print(zipcode)      #not only list of records
        print(email)
        print(phone)
        print(hire_date)
        print('-'*50)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    return menu2()
```

I need all records in one table|| codes bring data from Database as line by line without formatting> I need them in table

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are familiar with the pandas library, but I believe it is helpful here. I have never used it with mysql, but I have used it with psycopg2 and pyodbc, so I think the basic idea should work:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall(),columns = colnames)
```

creates a dataFrame (think python spreadsheet or python table) that uses the column names from the table you're querying.